# Usar um classe em outra classe

Tags: java, android

bom dia.

Sou novo em Java, mas vamos lá.

Tenho uma classe java e preciso usar todos os métodos dela em outra classe principal.

Tem um problema, já estou usando um extends nas duas classes.

Preciso usar todos metodos dessa classe(coloquei no txt por ser grande):

http://t4web.com.br/MainActivity

Nessa classe:

```
public class SocialFragment extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.social_layout,null);


}
```

}

Existe alguma forma de realizar esse procedimento sem chamar método por método ?

@Edit

Minha MainActivity é meu mapa com todas regras de negócios, preciso usar ela em uma das delas a baixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas estou com problemas, pois já estou usando o extends nas 2 classes.

Comment: Mostre o que você quer fazer, pode ser que tenha, depende do que você quer. Embora eu ache que não sem ser uma gambiarra monumental.

Comment: @bigown, fiz a edição. Obrigado.

Comment: @tharleycarvalho você não precisa sinalizar sua pergunta, deixe comentários para que todos os usuários vejam. Sinalização serve para indicar problemas graves em um tópico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em `SocialFragment` faça:

```
MainActivity mainActivity = null;

@Override
public void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
     mainActivity = (MainActivity)getActivity();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mainActivity = null;
}
```

Declare os métodos que deseja chamar como `public` em `MainActivity` e chame-os em `SocialFragment` assim:

```
if (mainActivity != null) {
    mainActivity.meuMetodo();
}
```

Comment: Alguma outra sugestão sem chamar métodos por métodos?

Comment: Se entendi bem, você tem um viewpager onde cada aba (tela) é um fragmento, e você quer incluir o mapa em uma das telas. Para isso deverá criar um novo fragmento e jogar todas as regras de negócio relacionadas ao mapa nesse fragmento, removendo-as da MainActivity.

Comment: Quando tento chamar os metodos ele da erro no onResume, na verdade ele nem chega a chamar os metodos. Olha o erro do Logcat > http://t4web.com.br/logs

Comment: Esqueça esse código que eu postei. Siga a orientação que eu coloquei depois.

Comment: Esse código só funcionaria se o SocialFragment estivesse adicionado à MainActivity mas pelo LogCat ele estava adicionado a uma Activity chamada iniciar.

Comment: esse é o problema, algumas funcionalidades não funciona com Fragement, somente com FragmentActivity. 

Em uma classe estou retornando todos os Fragment:

       public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            switch (position){
                case 0 : return new PrimaryFragment();
                case 1 : return new SocialFragment();
                case 2 : return new UpdatesFragment();
            }
            return null;
        }

Mas não consigo chamar como FragmentActivity, o problema é justamente transformar minha activity em um Framento.

Comment: Consegui converter minha activity para Fragment, porem não estou conseguindo criar SupportMapFragment do google maps usando o Fragment, segue o erro do logcast: http://t4web.com.br/logs . No mesmo arquivo, logo a baixo está minha activity.

Comment: Primeiro, não chame mais sua activity de MainActivity pois ela agora é um fragment. Fragments são adicionados a activities, portanto são conceitos diferentes. Segundo, ela não está consistente com o erro que está dando, porque o erro ocorre na linha 73 do método setUpMapIfNeeded e esse método não existe na activity. Poste a classe consistente com o erro que está dando.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda.

Consegui converter todo código para o Fragment, sobre o erro anterior consegui criar o SupportMapFragment usando o MapView -> https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView